# How can I determine if a YouTube video is part of any playlist?

Tags: youtube, playlist

There is a channel on YouTube with hundreds of videos, and many-many playlist.
I just want to know that the a video is part of any playlist? Without search filtering, and scrolling through hits .

Sometimes -if you watch a video- there is a drop-down list(which shows the place of the video in a playlist) at the right bottom corner of the video IF it is part of the playlist.
It is safe to say if this drop-down list is missing than the video is not part of any playlist?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rilLf.jpg)

Google did not help, I find only solutions which are as far complicated as scrolling trough 10 playlist searching for videos.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using YouTube's API? You would pass the video ID, and analyze the response. The exact method of analyzing would depend on your language (JS, python, C#, something else).

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not thinking about writing an API for this. Not even because I don't know how to do it. . Im just a user, and i just want to know a video is part of any playlist or not.

Comment: You don't have to write an API, you can use the official YouTube API with, for example, a bit of Javascript to get what you need. I don't think that you can get that information otherwise (as an ordinary user, simply by browsing YouTube).

Comment: @PhotoB quote: `...Without search filtering, and scrolling through hits` - I was going to suggest to use filters on the search page, but, if you don't want to use any of those features, then, it's not clear what you want to use for get this result...